# convert Rcpp::CharacterVector to std::string

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am trying to open a file within an [Rcpp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html) function, so I need the file name as a char* or std::string.

So far, I have tried the following:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

RcppExport SEXP readData(SEXP f1) {
    Rcpp::CharacterVector ff(f1);
    std::string fname = Rcpp::as(ff);
    std::ifstream fi;
    fi.open(fname.c_str(),std::ios::in);
    std::string line;
    fi >> line;
    Rcpp::CharacterVector rline = Rcpp::wrap(line);
    return rline;
}
```

But apparently, `as` does not work for `Rcpp::CharacterVector` as I get a compile time error.

```
foo.cpp: In function 'SEXPREC* readData(SEXPREC*)':
foo.cpp:8: error: no matching function for call to 'as(Rcpp::CharacterVector&)'
make: *** [foo.o] Error 1
```

Is there a simple way to get a string from the argument or somehow open a file from the Rcpp function argument?

Comment: does Rcpp::as<string>(ff) work?

Comment: @IanFellows, yup, that works!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`Rcpp::as()` expects a `SEXP` as input, not a `Rcpp::CharacterVector`.  Try passing the `f1` parameter directly to `Rcpp::as()`, eg:

```
std::string fname = Rcpp::as(f1);
```

Or:

```
std::string fname = Rcpp::as<std::string>(f1);
```

Comment: `Rcpp::as<std::string>` works with both `SEXP` and `Rcpp::CharacterVector`

Answer (score 18):

The real issue is that `Rcpp::as` requires that you specify the type you want to convert to manually, such as `Rcpp::as<std::string>`.

The input of all `as` overloads is always a `SEXP` so the compiler does not know which one to use and cannot make the decision automatically. that's why you need to help it. Things work differently for `wrap` which can use the input type to decide which overload it will use.